# hibernate jdk 11 не хочет работать

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jdk11

```
package ru.akaleganov.models;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class User {
    private int id;
    private String login;
    private String password;
    private Timestamp created;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Timestamp created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" + "id=" + id + ", login='" + login + '\'' + ", password='" + password + '\''
                + ", create=" + created + '}';
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernate</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="connection.password">444444</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>

    <mapping resource="ru/akaleganov/models/User.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

маппинг прописываю через xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="ru.akaleganov.models.User" table="users">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="login" column="login"/>
        <property name="password" column="password"/>
        <property name="created" column="create_date"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

так создаю таблицу

```
 create table if not exists  users(
id serial primary key,
login varchar(200),
password varchar(200),
create_date TIMESTAMP
);
```

зависимости: я уже не знаю какие ещё добавить

```
  <!--Hibernate-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0.Alpha2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>6.1.0.Alpha4</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-hikaricp</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0.Alpha2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0.Beta2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
     <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--END Hibernate-->
```

пробуем за тестить

```
public class UserTest {

    @Test
    public void modeltest() {
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                .configure()
                .buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        User user = new User();
        user.setLogin("test");
        session.save(user);
        System.out.println(session.createQuery("from User").list());
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

на выходе получается:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper$2 cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper$2 is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Integer is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.internal.IntegerJavaDescriptor.unwrap(IntegerJavaDescriptor.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.spi.IntegerSqlDescriptor$1.doBind(IntegerSqlDescriptor.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.sql.AbstractJdbcValueBinder.bind(AbstractJdbcValueBinder.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.expression.LiteralParameter.bindParameterValue(LiteralParameter.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcMutationExecutorImpl.execute(JdbcMutationExecutorImpl.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcMutationExecutorImpl.execute(JdbcMutationExecutorImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.entity.SingleTableEntityTypeDescriptor.executeOperation(SingleTableEntityTypeDescriptor.java:768)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.entity.SingleTableEntityTypeDescriptor.executeInsert(SingleTableEntityTypeDescriptor.java:384)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.entity.SingleTableEntityTypeDescriptor.executeInsert(SingleTableEntityTypeDescriptor.java:376)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.entity.SingleTableEntityTypeDescriptor.insertInternal(SingleTableEntityTypeDescriptor.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.spi.AbstractEntityTypeDescriptor.insert(AbstractEntityTypeDescriptor.java:885)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:643)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:30)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:685)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:677)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:672)
    at ru.akaleganov.models.UserTest.modeltest(UserTest.java:19)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

т.е. ругается на строчку

```
session.save(user);
```

и ещё компилятор подчёркивает в среде будто он не понимает что это, скрин прилагается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Гляньте [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050996/expected-type-java-lang-integer-actual-value-org-hibernate-id-identifiergener). Возможно, надо сменить генератор primaryKey

Comment: я же написал что прописываю всё через xml а не аннотации

Comment: В этом месте `<id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <generator class="identity"/>` поменяйте на native, так же как в ссылке которую я вам указал, там в ответе это было

Answer (score 2):

Проблема проявляется в Hibernate версии `6.0.0.Alpha2`, в последней стабильной версии `5.4.2.Final` такой проблемы нет.